# Moderation Panel Made With Buttons / Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Ello, I've just gotten into discord.py and im trying to do this project, Basically it's a command that gives you a moderation panel where you can ban people, kick people and dm people (for right now), I'm stuck on the part where it mentions the user to state the reason for the action. If you can help in any way on any part I thank you so much, I've only started 2 days ago so my apologies for any mistakes.

@

```
bot.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def button(ctx, member: discord.Member):
      button1 = Button(label="Ban", style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger, emoji="")
      button2 = Button(label="Kick", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, emoji="")
      button3 = Button(label="DM", style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey, emoji="")
    
      async def button1_callback(interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Please State The Reason For Banning {member.Mention}")
    
      async def button2_callback(interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Please State The Reason For Kicking {discord.Member.mention}")
    
      async def button3_callback(interaction):
         await interaction.response.send_message(f"Please State What You Would Like To Send To {member.Mention}")
    
      button1.callback = button1_callback
      button2.callback = button2_callback
      button3.callback = button3_callback
    
      view = View()
      view.add_item(button1)
      view.add_item(button2)
      view.add_item(button3)
      await ctx.send("Sup bozo", view=view)
```

Comment: Why are you not creating an event and give every button a `custom_id` if possible? You can then call the `interaction.author` and mention it in your `interaction.response`

Comment: Can you explain more please, I'm not sure where to place the custom_id in the code.

Comment: `Button(label="Ban", style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger, emoji="", custom_id="YourName")`. Which library are you using for buttons? Is this `discord.py`?

Comment: Thank you, I'm using pycord

Answer (score 0):

The updated code utilizes button custom IDs for streamlined interaction handling within the command function, eliminating the need for explicit callback functions. This enables direct button-to-action mapping, achieving the goal of providing interactive member action choices.

```
async def button(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    buttons = [
        Button(label="Ban", style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger, emoji="", custom_id="1"),
        Button(label="Kick", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, emoji="", custom_id="2"),
        Button(label="DM", style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey, emoji="", custom_id="3")
    ]

    view = View()
    for button_ in buttons:
        view.add_item(button_)

    await ctx.send("Sup bozo", view=view)

    def check(msg):
        return msg.channel == ctx.channel and msg.user == member and msg.data["component_type"] == 2

    try:
        res = await bot.wait_for("interaction", check=check)
        custom_id = res.data["custom_id"]
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    else:
        if custom_id == "1":
            await res.response.edit_message(f"Please State The Reason For Banning {member.mention}")

        elif custom_id == "2":
            await res.response.edit_message(f"Please State The Reason For Kicking {member.mention}")

        elif custom_id == "3":
            await res.response.edit_message(f"Please State What You Would Like To Send To {member.mention}")
```